# Css3pie works completely on localhost but only partially on remote server

Tags: asp.net, html, css, css3pie

I have a site online, it's a web app written in ASP.NET. When I copy HTML code of the site disaplyed, place it into a html file and run on localhost (Apache server), everything is ok and CSS3PIE works properly.

The problem is that on the server it works differently. First it didn't even work at all and the elements that had pie.htc behavior attached in css disappeared completely or let's rather say became transparent.

I stumbled upon an advice saying that `position: relative;` on the given element will solve the problem. It kind of did, but it was not satisfactory at all. The background was still transparent, parts of the elements disappeared and on hover it made other elements jump to a side by couple of pixels. Shadows worked, rounded corners also kind of worked but no gradients.

Comment: Pointing us to the site could help in this specific case.

Comment: I know, but client wanted the site to be kept secret, so sadly i cannot reveal it. So I guess my goal here is to find someone who had the same issue and managed to resolve it

Comment: In that case, I can only say http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: Yes they do, since they did on localhost. You obviously don't see the main problem here

Comment: Correct, I literally don't see it.

Comment: I don't think "dowebsitesneed..." applies to his problem. He isn't saying the site is looking different in different browsers. He is saying he is using the same browser but when viewing on an ASP server it's not working as it did locally on his apache server. That being said, the author has not given enough information since it appears to be a server issue but the author will not provide information about where to view the server or server config files. You may want to contact your server admin.

Answer (score 2):

**A couple of possibilities:**

**1)** The `.htc` file isn't being served with the correct mime-type. From the [CSS3 PIE Known Issues](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#content-type)

> IE requires that HTC behaviors are served up with a content-type
>   header of "text/x-component", otherwise it will simply ignore the
>   behavior. Many web servers are preconfigured to serve the correct
>   content-type, but others are not.
>
> If you have problems with the PIE behavior not being applied, check
>   your server configuration and if possible update it to use the correct
>   content-type. For Apache, you can do this in a .htaccess file:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

Is the problematic behavior on a server running IIS? If so, what version of IIS? [IIS 5 or higher should have the mime-type for .htc configured correctly](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx)

**2)** Perhaps it's a path problem, again from the [CSS3 PIE known issues](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#relative-paths)

> Relative paths
>
> There are two main issues related to relative paths in CSS: The
>   behavior URL
>
> IE interprets the URL for the behavior property relative to the source
>   HTML document, rather than relative to the CSS file like every other
>   CSS property. This makes invoking the PIE behavior inconvenient,
>   because the URL has to either be:
>
> > Absolute from the domain root — this makes the CSS not easily moveable between directories — or,
> >     Relative to the HTML document — this makes the CSS not easily reusable between different HTML files.
>
> URLs in PIE-interpreted CSS properties
>
> PIE does not parse the CSS stylesheets (to do so would be unacceptably
>   slow); it lets IE handle the parsing, selector querying, cascading,
>   etc. and then simply asks it for the resulting property values. This
>   means that when PIE gets a property value, it has no knowledge of the
>   context from which that value originated.
>
> As a result, for properties which contain URL values (such as
>   border-image or -pie-background), PIE cannot resolve those URLs
>   relative to the CSS file in which they appear. It resolves them
>   instead relative to the JavaScript execution context, which is the
>   location of the source HTML document.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's definitely not the second case, but when it comes to the first one, I don't know. Is it possible that wrong content type could result in partial applying of the pie?

Comment: @Elwhis If the code runs fine on your localhost and has problems on the production server, it's probably a path or server configuration issue. I haven't seen the partial application before, but seems possible. You didn't say what version of IIS, but it's easy enough to check. Load the .htc file in a browser directly and view the response headers (there are many ways to get this, but with the developer tools extension in Firefox: Information -> View Response Headers). This will give you the content type and probably also the version of IIS.

Comment: ok, so the content type is ok, it is text/x-component,
IIS version is 6.0

Comment: @Elwhis well, it's gotta be something on the server since it works on your local machine. If you're unwilling to share the server url I really don't see how we can help any more. My last suggestion would be to use the developer tools in IE to see if any errors are reported.